# ACF and PACF Autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, correlation, pacf

I have been trying to Understand correlation and tried it on my project and need help interpreting for a my case and in general.

I have the following results but finding it hard to interpret.
[click here for acf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNT6U.png)
Is there anyone who understands it better and can help explain how to interpret the acf and pacf?
[click here for pacf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLckA.png)